# Ubuntu 13.10 - is crashing the display not stable, how to fix it?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, kernel, display, bug-reporting

Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit latest version is installed in the HP EliteOne 800 all-in-one touch screen PC. Display is breaking over and over.

is 13.10 stable yet? Its not working at all.

[image]

Tried with Dell Inspiron One same 13.10 is unstable.

[image]

Comment: well stable definition is controversial. In my case i have Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit and for me is stable. I don't know how do you get 1.6k of reputation. Do you have nvidia, ati, intel? Another distro can deal with that system?

Comment: @user: it shift with Windows 8 default, and perfectly works with it. Ubuntu 13.10 is not working its Intel graphics card there Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th generation core processor integrated graphics controller.

Comment: of course that work with Windows 8. Is designed for that os.

Comment: OpenSUSE is compatible with HP, if OpenSUSE is then why latest Ubuntu 13.10 wont work? They are using same kernel. you got the point?